# Manipulate and plot images with R

Tags: r, image, plot

I would like to use R to build programmatically figures that would combine images of variable size (stored on my hard-drive) and numbers (e.g. a bird image and the size of the population).

For example:

- birds 1 https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/15/21/14/bird-35336_1280.png
- birds 2 https://www.goodfreephotos.com/albums/vector-images/blue-bird-vector.png
- birds 3 https://www.goodfreephotos.com/albums/vector-images/red-bird-vector.png

Let's say we have 5 birds n°1, 3 birds n°2 and 15 birds n°3. All the images have different size, some with color, some greyscaled...

At the end, I would like to have a plot like my screenshot (see "Result I would like to get" link): all images greyscaled, same image height and number of birds well aligned with the same height.

I've tried some code using R base plot functions but I'm struggling with the different resolutions and sizes... And it was so inelegant that I did not post it

Does someone have an idea?

[Result I would like to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52hsY.png)

Comment: look at the `imager` library.

Comment: imager is OK to load and modify images but for example I couldn't plot images and the number, all well aligned

Comment: No other ideas? I guess I should present things differently...